# Best way to create a table of data, and how to initialize it?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to create a table with String keyvalues and integer data. Right now I am leaning towards creating a two-dimensional HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

Is that going to be my fastest and most flexible option? I am using it to create a language model so there will be a lot of changes and frequent lookups. Also, is that the correct syntax? And how would I initialize it?

```
new HashMap<String, new HashMap<String, Integer>>
```

seems wrong to me for some reason but I can't place why.

Comment: do you need an hash map inside an hash map?

Comment: What value do you want to store fore each String key? An integer, a list of integers, a set of integers, or another String=>Integer map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also define your map like this:

```
map = new HashMap<Pair<String>,Integer>();
```

Where `Pair` has a reasonable definition (don't forget `equals` and `hashCode`!).

This is simpler (insert doesn't have to check whether the sub-map is created or not) and probably faster (only 1 hash lookup instead of 2).

If you know of some character that can't be in either of your strings, then you could just use `String` instead of `Pair<String>` where the key is the concatenation of the two keys with that character as a separator.

Comment: I was also about to suggest a composite key because I think it'll be a lot less hassle. But regardless of whether it's a 2D map or a composite key, if these are going to be used heavily, I might even go one step further and define an interface with convenience methods `get(K1 key1, K2 key2)` and `put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value)`.

Comment: Would this be faster than doing a HashMap HashMap like I was thinking of doing? I won't be learning about data structure speeds until next semester in school unfortunately, so I'm somewhat in the dark here.

Comment: @mavix: yes, this is probably faster and will use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: [Google Guava Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Google Guava is a quite handy library containing many useful collection and utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax `new HashMap<String, new HashMap<String, Integer>>` is not correct.

You can do this

```
map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>;
map.put("key", new HashMap<String, Integer>());
```

I.e. for each key you need to put a new sub-map instance.

Answer (score 0):

Maps would definitely work.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> myTable = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();

// Put a new "row" in the column "some_col"   
myTable.put("some_col", new HashMap<String, Integer>());

// put a value into some_col and some_row
myTable.get("some_col").put("some_row", 9);

// Get a value from some_col and some_row
Integer val = myTable.get("some_col").get("some_row");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash Map is fast and flexible, but may consume more memory. The define syntax is correct, for initialization:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
HashMap<String, Integer> record = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
record.put("key", 42);
map.put("key", record);
```